# How can i make an XML or JSON Request to an API

Tags: c#, html, xml, json

I'd like to find out a way to basically test an api that someone made, preferably by using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (C# specifically).

I know that I either need to send an XML or JSON Request, and I have the URL to the api but I have no idea where to begin. I mean ideally I would have n amount of text boxes with labels for each of the inputs in the request, where I can enter the amounts, click a submit button and then retrieve the values given from it. IF someone could give me insight on how to continue this, I would appreciate that.

Comment: That depends on what kind of api you are consuming. If you could give specifics I would be happy to help.

Comment: Check out POSTMan extension for Chrome.

Comment: We need some details about the service on the other end. You could start by looking at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..?

Comment: hmm I'm actually going to try the PostMan Extension, thanks alot. I realized I dont necessarily have to use c# if I'm just doing some quick testing. Appreciate all the feedback nonetheless guys

Comment: @Brant Is there a tutorial for this somewhere? hahahaha I dont even know how to send an xml request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I have used [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for this.
Really it is made for monitoring web calls, but it has the option to compose and send calls.

I'm not sure how to do this through Visual Studio though.

Comment: I've chosen to use fiddler, and since your answer was first :) i'll mark this as correct. Thanks !

Comment: If you are consuming a microsoft product there are way better ways to test then fiddler. You may want to give more details and get a real answer.

Comment: I think for the purposes of the testing I'm doing right now, this works well enough. Nonetheless I appreciate the help vikingben! Very thankful for the willingness to help.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [RESTClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) :

- It's simple
- It's light (just download & run, no installation)
- It comes with all needed features to test a RESTful API (and more)
- It's written in Java, so it's OS-agnostic
- It comes in two versions : [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) or [cli](/questions/tagged/cli)
- It's completely free and open-source
- You can save & load requests / responses

Answer (score 1):

I use Fiddler and love it, but [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) come to mind. Depends on what you're connecting to at the other end I suppose.